# AFNetworking "Undefined symbols for architecture i386" Error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have added all AFNetworking library files to my project(Which I downloaded from github). I didn't created any other view controller/class etc in my application. I just built my application and found 9 errors "Undefined symbols for architecture". Any help would be appreciated.

I listed down the list of errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

"_SecCertificateCopyData", referenced from:
-[AFURLConnectionOperation connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:] in AFURLConnectionOperation.o

"_SecCertificateCreateWithData", referenced from:___44+[AFURLConnectionOperation pinnedPublicKeys]_block_invoke in AFURLConnectionOperation.o

"_SecPolicyCreateBasicX509", referenced from:___44+[AFURLConnectionOperation pinnedPublicKeys]_block_invoke in AFURLConnectionOperation.o

-[AFURLConnectionOperation connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:] in AFURLConnectionOperation.o  "_SecTrustCopyPublicKey", referenced from:___44+[AFURLConnectionOperation pinnedPublicKeys]_block_invoke in AFURLConnectionOperation.o

-[AFURLConnectionOperation connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:] in AFURLConnectionOperation.o  "_SecTrustCreateWithCertificates", referenced from:___44+[AFURLConnectionOperation pinnedPublicKeys]_block_invoke in AFURLConnectionOperation.o

-[AFURLConnectionOperation connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:] in AFURLConnectionOperation.o "_SecTrustEvaluate", referenced from:___44+[AFURLConnectionOperation pinnedPublicKeys]_block_invoke in AFURLConnectionOperation.o

-[AFURLConnectionOperation connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:] in AFURLConnectionOperation.o  "_SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex", referenced from:-[AFURLConnectionOperation connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:] in AFURLConnectionOperation.o
```

"_SecTrustGetCertificateCount", referenced from:-[AFURLConnectionOperation connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:] in AFURLConnectionOperation.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: did you include the SystemConfiguration, Security and MobileCoreService Frameworks?

Comment: I think you need to add `SystemConfiguration.Framework` in you iOS project

Comment: Just add the Security Framework

Comment: I have just Added Security and MobileCoreService Frameworks,   My application is working fine now.  A big thanx friend.

Comment: You should accept the question that solved your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need to add `Security.framework` in you iOS project.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Sec` is not `SC`. The framework OP is looking for is Security, not SystemConfiguration.

Comment: @H2CO3 oh my mistake and i deserve down vote thank you so much. i will update it too.

Answer (score 4):

Include the "Security" Framework. Everything works fine then.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same problem but now I have found my fault.
Do check following frameworks are added if you are facing similar problem

1. Security.framework
2. SystemConfiguration.framework
3. MobileCoreServices.framework

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding the files of AFNetworking in your project then make sure that `AFNetworking.m` is  selected for the target memebership of your project.

You could fix it by opening your AFNetworking.m file and in file inspector just tick the target membership for your project target.

Also make sure to include all the relevant frameworks in your project in order to make AFNetworking working.
i.e, systemConfiguration, security frameworks.

Comment: -1 this is wrong, just look at the error message. It's not that **other** files don't find the symbols which are defined in `AFNetworking.m`. It's exactly that `AFNetworking.m`'s methods refer to `Security.framework`'s functions, so this doesn't solve the problem.